# References in color-scale conditional formatting formulae for ranges

Tags: worksheet-function, libreoffice, conditional-formatting, libreoffice-calc

I'm using Libreoffice Calc (v6.1b).

Suppose I have numeric data in sheet column, A and I'm applying conditional formatting to sheet column B. I want each cell of B to have a color on a scale depending on its corresponding A value. For example:

```
Cell B1 is Green when A1 is 0 turns Yellow as A1 approaches 1, turns Red when A1 approaches 2.
Cell B2 is Green when A2 is 0 turns Yellow as A2 approaches 1, turns Red when A2 approaches 2.
```

and so on. How do I make these relative references when entering a formula in Libreoffice's conditional formatting dialog?

Comment: +1 because the question and example are clear.  However, there is a great deal of information online about this topic already, and it would be good to indicate what you have researched and tried.

Comment: A conditional format using ColorScale that takes the values from a different column. I don't think it is currently supported by LibreOffice, but it'd be great.

Answer (score 0):

Select cells B1 to B3.  This way, B1 is the offset starting point.  So, in conditional formatting formulas, `A1` will indicate the cell to the left of the current cell, not necessarily the first row.

Now, under *Format -> Conditional Formatting -> Manage*, enter **Formula is** `A1=0` and *Apply Style* "Good" (that is, green).

Then add `A1=1` for "Neutral" (yellow) and `A1=2` for "Bad" (red).  Finally, hit OK.

[image: conditional formatting for B1:B3]

**EDIT**:

Color scales currently require `All Cells`, and cannot be used with `Formula is`.  So that leaves the following less-than-ideal solutions.

1. Write a macro to read the values and set the cell colors.  Re-run it whenever the values change, by a sheet event handler.
2. Create for example 10 different styles of slightly different color.  Then use [STYLE](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_STYLE_function) and VLOOKUP to choose which of these styles should be used in each row.
3. Create those 10 different styles but use conditional formatting with `Formula is` to choose which style.

Methods 1 and 2 are explained in detail along with examples at https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?t=55410.

One good approach might be to use method 2 above but write a macro to create 100 different styles.  Then the macro only needs to be run once to set up, and from then on, formulas can take care of the coloring.

Comment: Thanks for the example, but I don't want individual styles, I want a color scale... I guess I wasn't clear about that. Indeed, for the non-scale case you can find enough information online.