# LibreOffice Calc: Use different max value for color scale conditional formatting in each row

Tags: colors, conditional-formatting, libreoffice-calc

I have a dataset like the following (only much larger): Each row represents a task with a maximum number of points available in column `B`. Every column starting at `C` represents a Person with their score for every task.

[image: An example dataset]

Now, what I want to do is color every score according to the percentage of the total available points for that task. That is, I want to apply a color scale, but the maximum value is different for every row (it is the number in the `B` column). The result should look something like this.

[image: The desired output]

Is there any way to do this without manually defining the colorscale for each row separately? (As I mentioned, the real dataset is much larger.)

---

Here is the example dataset for you to test against.

```
no max Alice Bob Claudia David
1   10     9   7       6    10
2    7     7   7       3     7
3    9     7   5       6     9
4   12    10   8      12     5
5    5     4   2       3     4
6   10     6   2       4     7
```

Comment: As far as i see, there's no other way than defining the color scale for each row separately. But you may use a macro for this task, so you don't have to define it manually. See, for example, https://superuser.com/a/1331714/84724 or https://superuser.com/a/350443/84724 (Excel 2007 solution, also using a macro).

Comment: @tohuwawohu Thanks for the pointers, but those approaches don't seem to work for me. If I just copy the conditional formatting to each row, the cell referenced for the max value (e.g. `B2` in my example) doesn't change, so all rows use the max value from the first row. I think macros are probably the way to go but I'm having a hard time finding documentation on how to set up or edit conditional formats using macros. (I've never used one before.)

Comment: The macros i've linked don't _define_ the conditional formatting rules, they just _copy_ the the conditional formatting definition from a source range to a target range. I'll elaborate in an answer.

Comment: After some attempts, i didn't find a working way to copy/paste the conditional formatting from row 2 to the following rows. I've felt so free to add a post on forum.openoffice.org, waiting for the admins to approve it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After [filing a bug report](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=145465), i got a hint that there's a [different but known LO calc bug](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=145208) involved, thus i can only propose a workaround (which worked with your test data):

1. Define the conditional formatting for cell range C2:F2, with min defined as value "0" and max as formula "=INDIRECT("B" & ROW())". The INDIRECT() function takes a string that represents a cell reference, in this case "B3" for the third row, "B4" for the fourth and so on, dynamically built based on the current row number; INDIRECT will evaluate the cell reference, yielding the max value from column B for the current row. While the relative cell reference "=$B2" won't get adapted if copied to different rows, INDIRECT() should return the correct max cell.
2. Paste the format from C2:F2 to C3:F7, either by selecting C2:F2 and using the "Paste Format" button, or by copying and using "Paste Special" -> "Format".
3. Save the file ***as xlsx*** (!) and reopen it. Without this step (or when saving in ods format), the conditional formatting won't get updated according to the current row's max value. That's the bug we had to get around.

Now, the conditional formatting should work for the complete range B2:F7, based on the B value for each row. I've used a data bar as conditional formatting, because it shows very clear if incorrent min/max values are used.

Comment: Hmm, when I use `=INDIRECT("B" & ROW())` as the formula, save, close and reopen the file (even without copying anything), the color scale does not show up (no matter if I save as `ods` or as `xlsx`). That is, all cells get a white background (with the lines usually separating them disappearing). I guess that's a separate issue but it means this workaround doesn't work for me either. (I'm on Windows with an up-to-date LibreOffice.) :-(

Comment: Localized function names are not enabled ("Use English function names" is ticked in the settings and my UI is in English anyways). Pasting the formula directly in a cell works fine. Using it in the color scale also works initially, but only as long as the file isn't closed and reopened.

Comment: Yes, I did try with a fresh file. I have tested it both with LO 7.1.6.2 (latest "stable" version) and LO 7.2.2.2 (latest version period). This works fine on your end?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131018/discussion-between-schtandard-and-tohuwawohu).